# No texture being displayed for UI ImageElement Stride 4.2

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

Hey all I'm trying to set the Texture of an ImageElement in code as I need to use different images for different resources to represent the class of a player so mana, energy, rage and the skill images I wish to be dynamic so that what ever skill is first in the list is the first on the abilities bar I've done some debugging and I can see that the texture is loaded in Source.Texture but nothing is drawing

```
using System;
using Stride.Engine;
using Stride.UI;
using Stride.Graphics;
using Stride.UI.Controls;
using Stride.Rendering.Sprites;

namespace RPG3DPro
{
    public class PlayerUiManager : SyncScript
    {
        // Declared public member fields and properties will show in the game studio
        #region UIPages
        public UIPage PlayerUI { get; set; }
        public Player Player { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region UIElements
        private ImageElement Health = null;
        private ImageElement Resource = null;
        private ImageElement Skill1 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill2 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill3 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill4 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill5 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill6 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill7 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill8 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill9 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill10 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill11 = null;
        private ImageElement Skill12 = null;
        private TextBlock Level = null;
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureResource = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill1 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill2 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill3 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill4 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill5 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill6 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill7 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill8 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill9 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill10 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill11 = new();
        private SpriteFromTexture SpriteFromTextureSkill12 = new();
        #endregion
        #region Textures
        private Texture FireballTexture = null;
        private Texture BoltTexture = null;
        private Texture EnergyblastTexture = null;
        private Texture DeathballTexture = null;
        private Texture Fireballv2Texture = null;
        private Texture FirewallTexture = null;
        private Texture FireshieldTexture = null;
        private Texture CataclysmTexture = null;
        private Texture MeteoriteTexture = null;
        private Texture Meteoritev2Texture = null;
        #endregion
        private float HPWidthMax;
        private float HPHeight;
        #region Strings
        protected const string W = "Warrior";
        protected const string M = "Mage";
        protected const string R = "Ranger";
        protected const string K = "Monk";
        protected const string E = "Rouge";
        protected const string D = "Druid";
        private const string f = "Fireball";
        private const string ff = "Fireball V2";
        private const string fw = "FireWall";
        private const string me = "Meteorite";
        private const string me2 = "Meteorite V2";
        private const string b = "Bolt";
        private const string e = "Energy Blast";
        private const string d = "Deathball";
        #endregion
        private int SkillCount;
        private bool do_once = false;
        public override void Start()
        {
            // Initialization of the script.
            var root = PlayerUI.RootElement;
            Health = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("HP");
            Resource = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Resource");
            Skill1 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill1");
            Skill2 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill2");
            Skill3 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill3");
            Skill4 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill4");
            Skill5 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill5");
            Skill6 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill6");
            Skill7 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill7");
            Skill8 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill8");
            Skill9 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill9");
            Skill10 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill10");
            Skill11 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill11");
            Skill12 = root.FindVisualChildOfType<ImageElement>("Skill12");
            Level = root.FindVisualChildOfType<TextBlock>("Level");
            Level.Text = Player.CurrLevel.ToString();
            HPWidthMax = 127;
            Player.Name = CharacterSpawner.Name;
            switch (Player.ClassTypes)
            {
                case W:
                    Resource.Source.GetSprite().Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/HealthBar");
                    break;
                case M:
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/ManaBar");
                    Resource.Source = SpriteFromTextureResource;
                    Resource.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture;
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.IsTransparent = false;
                    break;
                case R:
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/EnergyBar");
                    Resource.Source = SpriteFromTextureResource;
                    Resource.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture;
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.IsTransparent = false;
                    break;
                case E:
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/EnergyBar");
                    Resource.Source = SpriteFromTextureResource;
                    Resource.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture;
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.IsTransparent = false;
                    break;
                case K:
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/EnergyBar");
                    Resource.Source = SpriteFromTextureResource;
                    Resource.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture;
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.IsTransparent = false;
                    break;
                case D:
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/EnergyBar");
                    Resource.Source = SpriteFromTextureResource;
                    Resource.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture;
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.IsTransparent = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/ManaBar");
                    Resource.Source = SpriteFromTextureResource;
                    Resource.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureResource.Texture;
                    SpriteFromTextureResource.IsTransparent = false;
                    break;
            }
            FireballTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/fireball_skill");
            BoltTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/bolt_skill");
            EnergyblastTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/Energyblast_skill");
            DeathballTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/deathball_skill");
            Fireballv2Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/fireballV2_skill");
            CataclysmTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/Cataclysm_skill");
            MeteoriteTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/metiorite_skill");
            Meteoritev2Texture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/metoritev2_skill");
            FirewallTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/firewall_skill");
            FireshieldTexture = Content.Load<Texture>("Textures/fireshield_skill");
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            // Do stuff every new frame
            var HpMax = Player.MaxHealth;
            var HpCurr = Player.HealthNow;
            var healthPercent = HpCurr / HpMax;
            Health.Width = HPWidthMax * (float)healthPercent;
            Resource.Width = HPWidthMax * (float)healthPercent;

            if (Level.Text != Player.CurrLevel.ToString())
            {
                Level.Text = Player.CurrLevel.ToString();
            }
            if (Player.Skills.Count > 0 && SkillCount != Player.Skills.Count)
            {
                do_once = true;
                SkillCount = Player.Skills.Count;
            }
            if (do_once)
            {
                do_once = false;
                switch (Player.Skills.Count)
                {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        SpriteFromTextureSkill1.IsTransparent = false;
                        Skill1.Source = SpriteFromTextureSkill1;
                        SpriteFromTextureSkill1.Texture = LoadSkillTexture(Player.Skills[0]);
                        Skill1.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureSkill1.Texture;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        SpriteFromTextureSkill1.IsTransparent = false;
                        SpriteFromTextureSkill2.IsTransparent = false;
                        Skill1.Source = SpriteFromTextureSkill1;
                        Skill2.Source = SpriteFromTextureSkill2;
                        SpriteFromTextureSkill1.Texture = LoadSkillTexture(Player.Skills[0]);
                        SpriteFromTextureSkill2.Texture = LoadSkillTexture(Player.Skills[1]);
                        Skill1.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureSkill1.Texture;
                        Skill2.Source.GetSprite().Texture = SpriteFromTextureSkill2.Texture;
                        break;
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        private Texture LoadSkillTexture(string skillName)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (skillName)
                {
                    case f:
                        return FireballTexture;
                    case b:
                        return BoltTexture;
                    case e:
                        return EnergyblastTexture;
                    case d:
                        return DeathballTexture;
                    case ff:
                        return Fireballv2Texture;
                    case me:
                        return MeteoriteTexture;
                    case fw:
                        return FirewallTexture;
                    case me2:
                        return Meteoritev2Texture;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Program.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried setting it all to a texture with no image in the engine with no joy I've tried using a Sprite sheet but can't find the default frame option that would set the correct image I would expect the UI to load with the textures I've set in code as well as the ones that are set in the engine it's self